# Sharepoint files > Salesforce records - Exteternal object - Files Connect

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, integration, sharepoint

I have a usecase to have a folder structure in Sharepoint and to sync all those files to salesforce records (According to the foldername (sharepoint, SF recordID) > Record ID in salesforce)

We have setup the native Sharepoint to Salesforce integration. And this works pretty well. I have the "items_sharepoint" object in Salesforce where i can traverse all the files in sharepoint.

When in Salesforce UI and manually adding a file, selecting the external storage and adding the file, it gets 'hard copied' onto the Salesforce Record. This works exacly how we would want it. (In the back, it creates a contentDocument and contentDocumentLink to that record).

Now my challange is to do above programatically. In apex (or flow?) I want to traverse the files in the external object "items_sharepoint" and select a item and 'hard copy' it over to a salesforce record. Exactly how I would manually do this in the UI.

I just can't seem to figure out how to replicate those actions via apex.

So in summary
Grab an sharepoint item in the external object "items_sharepoint" From this create a contentdocument and contentdocument link. The link shouldn't be a problem, but how do I go from the external obect record to a content document?

What I tried
We can utilize the sharepoint API to fetch the document, but then we are limited to the 12mb APEX limit. Whereas via the UI I can attach much lager files manually so i want to use that same flow to hardcopy the files into Salesforce.

The setting for the sharepoint integration is set to "Hard copy when linking" true.

Files connect external object SOQL documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_connect_search.htm&type=5